# Are SQL concatenations possible using the JDBC to ODBC bridge?

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, odbc, ms-access-2003, squirrel-sql

When I run a query using concatenation of fields in MS Access I can write the following and it works fine:

```
SELECT e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName + " " + e.MiddleName AS Attendant FROM (EMPLOYEES e INNER JOIN PAY pay ON e.SocialSecurityNumber = pay.Pay_Emp_ID) INNER JOIN Patients pat ON pay.Pay_Pat_ID = pat.PatientID;
```

But if I try to run the same query using the JDBC / ODBC Bridge in SQuirreL SQL I get an error message instead:

```
Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
SQLState:  07001
ErrorCode: -3010
```

Does ODBC require some other syntax that's different from MS-Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access ODBC driver allows concatenation but seems to have an issue with those double quote characters ... at least in this context.  Based on testing from VBScript, I think your query may work if you substitute single for double quotes:

```
SELECT e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName + ' ' + e.MiddleName AS Attendant
FROM
    (EMPLOYEES e INNER JOIN PAY pay
    ON e.SocialSecurityNumber = pay.Pay_Emp_ID)
    INNER JOIN Patients pat
    ON pay.Pay_Pat_ID = pat.PatientID;
```

However, I don't know Java so have no idea whether that bridge feature may garble the ODBC communication somehow.  But submitting that query directly through the Access ODBC driver did work for me.

Comment: I think you're right about the double quote characters, it doesn't like them for some reason and every time I use them in a query I get that same parameters error.